# SQL Server and repeating decimals

Tags: sql-server, decimal, calculation

How to deal with repeating decimals numbers in sql server in calculations ?

ex: 1/3 = 0.33333333333

but when i use it again in my calculations it gives me invalid numbers

3* 0.33333=0.9999999 not 1

Comment: you will have to understand that `SQL` works on `scalar data types`.. if you don't define as what the result should be SQL could give you either an error or an undesired result. thus, using `cast` to get the right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be you're not using enough precision with your decimal places.

For example, note the below:

```
DECLARE @f float;

SET @f = 0.333333333333333;
SELECT @f * 3;
SET @f = 0.3333333333333333;
SELECT @f * 3;
```

Notice the first `SELECT` returns `0.999999999999999`, however the second returns `1`.